# Why does JWT::decode() in PHP keep saying that my header is sending a null value?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, firebase, jwt

I have some PHP code where I am to take a JWT as a header from the client side, decode this JWT and get some data out of it.
Here's the code

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'connection.php';
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
header("Access-Conrol-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

    
$skey = 'some_crazy_long_secret_key_I_used';
$headers = getallheaders();
$jwt = $headers["Authorization"];
$mainJwt = explode(" ", $jwt)[1];
echo $mainJwt;
$decoded_jwt = JWT::decode($mainJwt, new Key($skey, 'HS256'));
echo "done!";
```

The issue I have here is that I keep getting error messages from heroku like this:

*2022-09-29T19:48:22.536385+00:00 app[web.1]: [29-Sep-2022 19:48:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "Authorization" in /app/getactivitiescount.php on line 18
2022-09-29T19:48:22.536705+00:00 app[web.1]: [29-Sep-2022 19:48:22 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  explode(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /app/getactivitiescount.php on line 19
2022-09-29T19:48:22.536929+00:00 app[web.1]: [29-Sep-2022 19:48:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /app/getactivitiescount.php on line 19
2022-09-29T19:48:22.537968+00:00 app[web.1]: [29-Sep-2022 19:48:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(): Argument #1 ($jwt) must be of type string, null given, called in /app/getactivitiescount.php on line 22 and defined in /app/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:90
2022-09-29T19:48:22.537989+00:00 app[web.1]: Stack trace:
2022-09-29T19:48:22.538116+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 /app/getactivitiescount.php(22): Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode()
2022-09-29T19:48:22.538137+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 {main}
2022-09-29T19:48:22.538292+00:00 app[web.1]: thrown in /app/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php on line 90*

Here's the code I have on the client side:

```
axios.get(`${API_URL}`, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }
}).then((response)=>{console.log(response.data)})
```

Here's the error I get on the client side

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hazloapi.herokuapp.com/getactivitiescount.php' from origin 'https://hazlotodo.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*

Comment: First you have a typo in `header("Access-Conrol-Allow-Credentials: true");` you wrote `Control` instead of `Control` but I don't think that is the problem, can you try to add `X-Requested-With` to your Allow-Headers.

Comment: Thanks Akkaya, I've corrected what you noticed in the Allow-Credentials, and I've equally added the X-Requested-With to the Allow-Headers, but non of it seems to work

Comment: Can you change to `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");`

Comment: Okay, let me try that now

Comment: Still throws same errors

Comment: I don't know why but seems like your `$headers["Authorization"];` is null. Maybe you may try to use different approach to access the headers like `apache_request_headers();` except that there shouldn't be any errors about CORS now. All the headers are correct. You can try to assign a static value to `$jwt` to make sure your code works but the problem is that you can't access that header.

Comment: I think I just noticed something.

When I try to echo out just the $headers["Authorization"] without the JWT::decode() method, it actually returns the JWT sent from the client side.
But once I try to decode that JWT using the JWT::decode() method, I get those errors

Comment: You should also check `explode(" ", $jwt)` there is nothing at index 1 of this. Maybe your Authorization header format is wrong. I can't say much without seeing and trying.

Comment: Hi @Praisecodes, were you able to fix this issue? I am also facing the same issue with firebase/php-jwt6.4 and php7.3. Please help me how I can fix this.